# how create .so file on Eclipse opencv cpp (c++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, shared-libraries, .so

i developed Any source on eclipse c++ (+ openCV, and compile tool is mingw)

then, i want create ".so file" for use in the Android studio.

so, I wonder how I can make .so files in Eclipse or other tools.

Please help me ...

my os : windows10

Comment: [Using Eclipse for develop Android app mixed Java and C/C++ code](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.in/2014/07/using-eclipse-for-develop-android-app.html)  this may get you started and for OpenCV complete tutorial at [OpenCV4Android SDK](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the few resources which can get you started

[Using Eclipse for develop Android app mixed Java and C/C++ code](http://falsinsoft.blogspot.in/2014/07/using-eclipse-for-develop-android-app.html)

[Android Native Development Kit](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/android/android_ndk.html)

[OpenCV4Android SDK](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/O4A_SDK.html)

[Android Development with OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#dev-with-ocv-on-android)